# how to generate rig without facial bones?

Tags: rigging

I would like to ask how to generate rig after deleting some small bones from cat meta-rig of Armature.

those two pictures are the behavior of original rig.

but at third picture, when I delete facial bones, I get error saying "ORG-nose not found"

I noticed I have to set "rigify_type" to none in Bone properties panel, but I cant find the property in my version,

Where can I set the meta-rig to not related to deleted bones??

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could generate rig by following the process below. 
first,duplicate the bone which had links to deleted bones.
then delete the original one, and rename the new one to be same name with old one.